# Making the first image in a row be gone with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a list with an option to delete them. However, no one can ever have zero and must have at least one. So I thought at the start of page load to make the first `<a>` to the delete be gone.

I tried this:

`$(".delete-language").children(':first').attr('display', 'none');`

and nothing.

Here is it:

`<a id="1" name="40" href="#" class="delete-language"><img style="margin-left:7px;" src="images/icons/cross.png" alt="Delete" title="Remove" display="none"></a>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.attr('display', 'none')` is a bit wrong as `display` is not an HTML attribute.

If you want to modify the css directly, use `.css('display', 'none')`

**Better yet**

```
$('.delete-language img').first().hide();
```